# Need help getting rails server to work

Tags: server, byebug

So I feel incredibly frustrated. I am doing www.railstutorial.org and they require a very specific version of rails (4.2.2). I have installed it as they wanted. Put in their Gemfile specs on their "hello_app" app they provided. When I run "rails server" I get an error message saying that "byebug" is erroring. I try to install earlier and later versions of bye bug and I get the same error message. Can someone please help me? I feel pretty lost.

The tutorial is at the url below.

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#code-hello_action

```
 alopex@alopex-TH55-HD:~/workspace/hello_app$ more Gemfile
 source 'https://rubygems.org

 gem 'rails',                '4.2.2'
 gem 'sass-rails',           '5.0.2'
 gem 'uglifier',             '2.5.3'
 gem 'coffee-rails',         '4.1.0'
 gem 'jquery-rails',         '4.0.3'
 gem 'turbolinks',           '2.3.0'
 gem 'jbuilder',             '2.2.3'
 gem 'sdoc',                 '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
 gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
 gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
 gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
 gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

alopex@alopex-TH55-HD:~/workspace/hello_app$ bundle install

 Gem::InstallError: byebug requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
 An error occurred while installing byebug (3.4.0), and Bundler cannot  continue.
 Make sure that `gem install byebug -v '3.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.

 alopex@alopex-TH55-HD:~/workspace/hello_app$ sudo gem install byebug -v 3.4.0
 ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
 byebug requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this problem in this way:

- Open your application's Gemfile
- remove: `gem 'byebug'`
- replace it with: `gem 'pry-byebug', platform: [:ruby_20]`

Answer (score 1):

It isn't `rails` issue: `byebug` requires Ruby version to be `2.0` at least. You can check your Ruby version with `ruby -v`, I guess it is `1.9.3` in your case. You can use [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to install actual Ruby version on your system.

Also, you can try to remove `byebug` from Gemfile and try to run `bundle` again. Maybe other gems can run with `ruby 1.9.3`, and you can learn `rails` without dealing with rvm.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I appreciate it. I'll let you know how it pans out!